# How to extract fields from different lines in a log file and combine the results into a single output?

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to implement a script which automatically reads in the log file of a next generation sequencing data analysis run and reports the read counts after each step of the analysis. The log files are always formatted in the same way.

For example, the lines containing the samples process begin with "Will parse" and the sample name is in the fourth column (field). Similarly the lines containing the outputted reads begin with "Trimmed output" and the number of outputted reads is in the third column (field) of those lines. I have used grep commands to extract the sample names and the number of reads to two new files. For extracting the file names: "grep "Will" PCOL.5_2016-11-03_090036694.log | cut -d' ' -f4 > file1". And for extracting the number of reads outputted after each step: "grep "Trimmed output:" PCOL.5_2016-11-03_090036694.log | cut -d ' ' -f 3,6 > file2".

Now I would like to combine (merge) the names of the samples in file1 with the number of reads outputted from file2. Line 1 in file1 corresponds to line 1 in file2 and line 2 in file1 corresponds to line 2 in file2 and so on. In other words, for sample #1 in the first line of file1 the number of reads outputted is in the first line of file2, and for sample #2 in the second line of file1 the number of reads outputted is in the second line of file2, etc. The script should then output something like this:

```
sample #1 reads_1
sample #2 reads_2
```

Until all of the read outputs are returned for all of the samples. My question is then what would be the best way to do this? Speed is not a necessary consideration here because the log files in question are not very large - usually less than a thousand lines. I came to programming rather late in life. The shell and its most basic commands ("grep", "cat", "ls", "mkdir", "head", "tail", etc) are familiar to me and I am constantly trying to learn more. Is there some shell command or regular expression that I could use to filter the data in the log file and get the result that I want? Or would it better to try to do this using R or Python? For example, if I would read the two files that I obtained using the grep command into Python and then process them in Python with a routine something like the following:

```
def main(file1,file2):
     #put everything in try-catch
     f1 = open(file1, 'r')
     f2 = open(file2, 'r')
     output = ""
     while not EOFerror: #find the proper way to end file reading
         output+=f1.readline()
         output+="\t"
         output+=f2.readline()
         output+="\n"
         print(output)
         output=" "

     f1.close()
     f2.close()

     return output
```

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: Please format everything

Answer (score 0):

So this would be a case where you could use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) to take care of this task. In fact you could probably use it from the beginning, i.e. where you are using `grep`. Though if you already have a process working with `grep` I would say to stick with it.

Assuming the files are delimited in some kind of standard way (commas, tabs, '|', etc...) you can easily read them into [`pandas.DataFrame`'s](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) and then merge them along the axis. So for example something like this:

```
samples = pd.read_csv(sample_filename, sep=separator_character)
reads = pd.read_csv(reads_filename, sep=separator_character)

output = samples.join(reads)
output.to_csv(output_filename, index=False, sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the two data sets in two separate files, assuming they are equal in the number of lines contained, you could merge them together using the 'paste' command.

```
paste file1 file2 > mergedoutput
```

In my personal experience, I've come to realize that text parsing in bash is limiting and that the better way to go about it is to turn to a language like Python(2.7). You could achieve the same result using its build-in string util methods split(), startswith() and a few conditional statetemnts.